# ffmpeg, old video tapes, is this command right? pal/secam/ntsc, etc

Tags: ffmpeg, recording

I was trying to thought about the old command line I was using few years ago do digitalize (or record) old VHS videotapes, to a common digital file (.avi/mp4)

Here is the old one:

> ffmpeg -f alsa -i hw:0,1 -f v4l2 -channel 1 -i /dev/video0 -standard 3 -vcodec mpeg1video -b 2500k -acodec mp2 -t 00:28:50 -vf yadif /home/user/backup.mpg

And here is the new one:

> ffmpeg -f alsa -i hw:0,1 -f v4l2 -channel 1 -i /dev/video0 -r 25 -standard 3 -vcodec mpeg2video -standard PAL -b 2500k -acodec mp2 -t 00:25:20 -vf yadif /home/user/sortie.mp4 -y

I was trying to use libx264 with mkv, but it makes the computer running very slow to play it. It's an old computer with a RCA video input for recording. It runs old Linux of 2010's, but it's working well. No internet access on that PC.

Does the second command look right?

Comment: "very slow to play it": do you mean to encode the file? If yes I would do that in two parts: digitalize the tape to mpeg2 with minimal compression (-b 5000k for instance) and to pcm (uncompressed) for the sound, and then recompress it it to h264/aac on a more recent computer.

Answer (score 0):

It appears

> -standard PAL

is no longer in current FFmepeg releases, though for saving tapes FFV1 and QTGMC/BWDIF de-interlacing is now pretty much the de-facto playback/archive standard I was looking for proper PAL flagging for V210/V410, but you might want to have a look at [VHS-Decode](https://github.com/oyvindln/vhs-decode) when it comes to analogue tape capture and exporting to video.

Comment: The OP is using a "old Linux of 2010's", so probably an old ffmpeg version as well.